# Setting up shoppe-notification-emails gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I'm hoping to add the shoppe-notification-emails gem (https://github.com/danquinney/notification-emails) to my Shoppe project (using: https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe).

I did the standard gemfile mods followed by running bundle install, and it seemed to work fine.  However when I try to manually invoke the notification email call in rails console (Shoppe::NotificationMailer.order_received(order).deliver), it says "uninitialized constant Shoppe::NotificationMailer".  This leads me to believe that the notifications mailer engine isn't correctly added to my project.  The github page for the notification-emails project doesn't really have any extra great setup info, anyone have any insight here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoppe actually ships with a built in mailer.  Make sure you have your mailer setup in both production.rb and development.rb

Then ensure that your mailer is setup on the /shoppe/settings page on the application.

Your .rb file should look something like this:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :user_name            => ENV['USERNAME'],
      :password             => ENV['PASSWORD'],
      :authentication       => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

replace the fields as necessary although the above is setup for gmail and you would just need to replace USERNAME AND PASSWORD fields.